# CKEditor5: prevent attributes being copied to new paragraph on enter

Tags: ckeditor5

I am working on a project that allows users to inject content into the editable.  I have added a `contentid` attribute to the paragraph so I can keep track of what has been added and where it is.

```
<p contentid="1">some default content</p>
```

When enter is pressed from within that paragraph, the next paragraph that is entered also has the `contentid="1"` attribute.  I want the new paragraph to not have the `contentid` attribute.

I'm trying to determine how/where best to achieve this.  I have been hacking around with listening to the enter key and `schema.addChildCheck` but not making much progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick.  Maybe a little hacky.. but realized that the selection is always in the newly created element. So I didn't need to find a reference to it in a callback, I could just grab the new paragraph from the current selection.

```
editor.commands.get( 'enter' ).on( 'afterExecute', () => {
  const block = first( editor.model.document.selection.getSelectedBlocks() );
  editor.model.change( writer => {
    writer.removeAttribute( 'contentid', block );
  });
});
```

Comment: I think it's the easiest way. Either listening to `afterExecute` or `execute` with a low priority.